# If statements in .phtml and .php

Tags: if-statement, php

I am having trouble understanding the file extension .phtml .From what i have read, it is supposed to be a way of using html and php together(please correct me if i am mistaken). What i am trying to do is very simple, I have a php variable, and if it fulfils a certain condition, some html code should be executed, if not some other html code should be executed. The code i have is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
$code = "dk";
?>

<?php if($code == "dk"): ?>
<p>
1</p>    

</br>


<?php else: ?>
<p>
2</p>     

</br>

<?php endif; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

The output I get when I save and run it as a .php file is only "1", but with .phtml I get "1 2". Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Extension doesn't matter it's about the parser who parses the file :)

Comment: okay thanks to all of you I know that its about the parser but i am trying to modify a magento web shop. The .phtml file was already there with a lot of if statements like the ones i wanted to write. I don't want to do major changes on the server. Is there any way?

Comment: @Revangelis I think it's the simplest solution. You might need to change all files referring to other files (like `include "something.phtml"` to `...php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure to run `.php/.phtml` extensions, so

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .html in your `httpd.conf` file to run phtml file

else you will see the whole code block like if you save the above code in `xyz.phtml` and run it via `http://localhost/xyz.phtml`

**EDIT**

After URL provided in the comments I checked the link and found your PHP code is actually rendered in the View source..please check yourself by viewing the source of this page, so `1 2` is rendered as a part of HTML u mentioned but since the server is not able to understand it silently induced the PHP logical code as well without going into the logical implementation part, hope it makes sense to you.

[LINK PROVIDED](http://shop2.xsmoke.com/timer2.phtml)

Comment: well i am modifying a magento web shop actually, and it is a .phtml that was already there. i am kinda afraid to do major changes. besides, in the file there were already php if statements like those i wanted to write. does that mean that they also don't work?

Comment: @Revangelis ..ohh then dont that ..let me update my answer on you comments

Comment: @Revangelis can u plz confirm what values you are getting in phtml

Comment: "1 2" with my original code. http://shop2.xsmoke.com/timer2.phtml you can see for yourself

Comment: Sooo.. why do i get both "1" and "2"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31575/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-revangelis)

Answer (score 2):

One of PHP files' strengths / weaknesses is that you can easily mix PHP and HTML.

In your case, I think your server is not configured to interpret as PHP files that end in .phtml, so the PHP is entirely ignored. Have a look at the page source of the page that outputs "1 2" to see if it's true.

You can have any extension you want be interpreted as PHP, even .html, but that will cause extra overhead of course. If you're running Apache, and want .phtml to be parsed too, adding a line like

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml

Should do the trick. Choosing a different extension can help hide that you're using PHP, if you're not already using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between .phtml and .php files. They are both intended to be a php code, which might have some HTML parts.

Your problem is that your server does not know, how to treat .phtml files. You can change the file extension to php (usually after installing the PHP changes your server settings automatically), or accept [swapnesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17041494/2088851) or [J Griffiths's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17041535/2088851) answer.

In fact PHP can parse any file with any extension, it might be even .html or .jpg, if you like. This does not matter*), as the header is most important.

Your code is correct from the PHP point of view, you need to change the server settings.

*) it can in some older Internet Explorer browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>
<?php echo (($code == "dk") ? "1" :"2"); ?>
</p>
</br>
```

This will work on both .php and .phtml

Don't know why you are doing code redundant this is optimize code also.

Comment: It doesn't matter what extension file has it's about parsing it by parser.

Comment: @Robert I know it and I have given the optimal solution to OP.

Comment: @Revangelis I have updated the code as I have forgot closing bracket. now check again. hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: i still get nothing with .phtml and "1" with .php